# gdb can't run programs linked against libcrypto

Tags: qt, gdb, raspberry-pi

On raspbian , I can't run a program linked with libcrypto from gdb. It doesn't matter what the program contains. Example:

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/pi/test/test 
Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x400844c0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
(gdb) signal SIGILL
Continuing with signal SIGILL.
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x400844c8 in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
(gdb) signal SIGILL
Continuing with signal SIGILL.
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
[Inferior 1 (process 1566) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

*

Comment: do you have the debug library?

Comment: i installed gdb debugger and i don't know ,how to check availability of debug library?

Comment: in order to be able to debug, you will need a debug build of libcrypto, the release version will not contain the debug symbols, if you have it it will probably be named libcryptod and will be much larger, so your debug build needs to link against that

Comment: Thanks for your help..!!!